Tally: Ledger Outstanding Report Exporting Blank PDF Files
I'm trying to export the Ledger Outstanding report from Tally using the TDL (Tally Definition Language) script below. The script runs successfully but the exported file is blank, i.e., it doesn't contain the report data.
Here's the code I'm using:
[Function: ExportLedgerGroup] 
Variable : LedgerName22       : String 
Variable : ContactNumber      : String 
Variable : PrintFileName      : String 
Variable : ExportedFilePath   : String

;; Confirm action
01 : Query Box : "Do you want to export reports?" : Yes : No
02 : If : $$LastResult

    ;; Ensure export directory exists
    03 : If : NOT $$IsDirectory:"LedgerOutstandingReports"
        04 : Make Dir : "LedgerOutstandingReports"
    05 : End If

    ;; Walk through the filtered collection of visible rows
    06 : Walk Collection : LWcollevc
        
        08 : SET : ContactNumber : $LedgerMobile:Ledger:$Name

        10 : Msg Box : "Contact Missing" : "No contact number for ledger: " + ##LedgerName22
        
        ;; Generate file name for export
        15 : SET : PrintFileName : "LedgerOutstandingReports" + "\" + ##LedgerName22 + "_" + $$String:##SVToDate + ".pdf"
        16 : SET : SVExportFormat : $$SysName:PDF
        17 : SET : SVPrintFileName : $$MakeExportName:##PrintFileName:##SVExportFormat
        18 : SET : SVOpenFileAfterExport : No

        ;; Export report for the ledger
        19 : EXPORT REPORT : Ledger Outstandings : No : No

        ;; Get the exported file path
        20 : SET : ExportedFilePath : $$GetFileFullPath:##SVPrintFileName

    27 : End Walk

    ;; Completion message
    28 : Msg Box : "Process Complete" : "All visible rows have been processed and sent."
29 : End If
30 : Return

[Collection: LWcollevc] 
Data Source : Report : All 
Fetch       : Name, LedgerMobile, ClosingBalance 
Filter      : IsNameNotEmpty

[System: Formula] 
IsNameNotEmpty : NOT $$IsEmpty:$Name

Expected Behavior
The script should generate a PDF file for each ledger visible in the collection (LWcollevc) and save it in the "LedgerOutstandingReports" directory with the appropriate filename.
Observed Behavior
The script executes, and the file is created, but the generated PDF is blank with no data from the Ledger Outstanding report.
What I Have Tried

Verified that the collection LWcollevc is fetching the correct ledgers using Msg Box.

Checked the generated file paths, and they are pointing to the correct location.

Ensured that the "Ledger Outstanding" report is accessible and contains data for the selected ledgers when viewed manually.


Questions:

Is there an issue with how the EXPORT REPORT function is being used?

Do I need to configure additional parameters for EXPORT REPORT to include data in the file?

Could this issue be caused by the data source or filter in the collection (LWcollevc)?


Any guidance on what I might be missing or doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
